# Mongodb fails to start -> presents weird error logs

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

When I moved my environment from my local (mac) to my server (ubuntu) I unzipped my directory and the server installed with `npm install` with no errors or warnings, but my database was failing so I decided to reinstall it based on this tutorial (well, `apt-remove mongo*` first)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

but then I get a

```
Job for mongodb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongodb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Does anyone know what any of this means?

```
-- Unit mongodb.service has begun starting up.
Jun 20 03:54:18 ip-172-31-16-163 mongodb[25271]:  * Starting database mongodb
Jun 20 03:54:19 ip-172-31-16-163 mongodb[25271]:    ...fail!
Jun 20 03:54:19 ip-172-31-16-163 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 20 03:54:19 ip-172-31-16-163 sudo[25268]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 20 03:54:19 ip-172-31-16-163 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: An object/document-oriented database.
-- Subject: Unit mongodb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mongodb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jun 20 03:54:19 ip-172-31-16-163 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 20 03:54:19 ip-172-31-16-163 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks familiar. Check ownership of files. Files in dbPath, mongod.run -lock file, keyfile...

Basically all those files what are listed at your `/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command and Its works for me

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb
```